# How to add for loop inside if condition in Jolt transformation

Tags: json, transform, jolt

I have following input JSON where I want to add for loop inside if condition

**Input** :

```json
[
  {
    "sports": {
      "percent": "10%",
      "feeType": [
        {
          "discount": 12345,
          "sport_fee_type": "Discounted fee",
          "fee_details": [
            {
              "total": 1117.3,
              "sports_catagory": "Cricket"
            },
            {
              "total": 6187.79,
              "sports_catagory": "Football"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "sport_fee_type": "Recurring fee",
          "fee_details": [
            {
              "total": 1117.3,
              "sports_catagory": "Cricket sport"
            },
            {
              "total": 6187.79,
              "sports_catagory": "Football"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "sport_fee_type": "Non Recurring fee",
          "fee_details": [
            {
              "total": 1117.3,
              "sports_catagory": "Cricket"
            },
            {
              "total": 6187.79,
              "sports_catagory": "football"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  }
]
```

**Specs**:

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "@sports": {
          "@percent": "additionalInfo[#1].value",
          "#percent": "additionalInfo[#1].property",
          "@feeType": {
            "*": {
              "sport_fee_type": {
                "Discounted fee": {
                  "#discountAmount": "additionalInfo[&3].property",
                  "@2,discount": ["additionalInfo[&3].value", "discountedPrice"],
                  "@2,fee_details": {
                    "*": {
                      "total": ["billing.feeSummary[&5].sportsCategories[&1].amount"],
                      "sports_catagory": "billing.feeSummary[&5].sportsCategories[&1].sportType"
                    }
                  },
                  "#DISCOUNTED": "billing.feeSummary[#2].feeType"
                },
                "Non Recurring fee": {
                  "@2,fee_details": {
                    "*": {
                      "total": "billing.feeSummary[&5].sportsCategories[&1].amount",
                      "sports_catagory": "billing.feeSummary[&5].sportsCategories[&1].sportType"
                    }
                  },
                  "#NON_RECURRING": "billing.feeSummary[#4].feeType"
                },
                "Recurring fee": {
                  "@2,fee_details": {
                    "*": {
                      "total": "billing.feeSummary[&5].sportsCategories[&1].amount",
                      "sports_catagory": "billing.feeSummary[&5].sportsCategories[&1].sportType"
                    }
                  },
                  "#RECURRING": "billing.feeSummary[#4].feeType"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  { // convert the values of sportType attributes to uppercase 
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "billing": {
        "feeSummary": {
          "*": {
            "sportsCategories": {
              "*": {
                "sportType": "=toUpper"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  { // convert the values of sportType attributes to uppercase 
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "billing": {
        "feeSummary": {
          "*": {
            "sportsCategories": {
              "*": {
                "sportType": "=split(' ',@(1,&))"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  { // convert the values of sportType attributes to uppercase 
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "billing": {
        "feeSummary": {
          "*": {
            "sportsCategories": {
              "*": {
                "sportType": "=join('_',@(1,&))"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

**Expected Output**:

```json
{
  "additionalInfo": [
    {
      "value": "10%",
      "property": "percent"
    },
    {
      "property": "discountAmount",
      "value": 12345
    }
  ],
  "discountedPrice": 12345,
  "billing": {
    "feeSummary": [
      {
        "sportsCategories": [
          {
            "amount": 1117.3,
            "sportType": "CRICKET"
          },
          {
            "amount": 6187.79,
            "sportType": "FOOTBALL"
          }
        ],
        "feeType": "DISCOUNTED"
      },
      {
        "sportsCategories": [
          {
            "amount": 1117.3,
            "sportType": "CRICKET_SPORT"
          },
          {
            "amount": 6187.79,
            "sportType": "FOOTBALL"
          }
        ],
        "feeType": "RECURRING"
      },
      {
        "sportsCategories": [
          {
            "amount": 1117.3,
            "sportType": "CRICKET"
          },
          {
            "amount": 6187.79,
            "sportType": "FOOTBALL"
          }
        ],
        "feeType": "NON_RECURRING"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can consider using the array indexes to loop through them by **[&5]** and **[&1]** identifiers such as

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "sports": {
          "percent": {
            "@": "additionalInfo[0].value",
            "#discountAmount": "additionalInfo[0].property"
          },
          "feeType": {
            "*": {
              "discount": {
                "@": ["additionalInfo[1].value", "discountedPrice"],
                "$": "additionalInfo[1].property"
              },
              "sport_fee_type": {
                "Discounted fee": {
                  "@2,fee_details": {
                    "*": {
                      "total": "billing.feeSummary[&5].sportsCategories[&1].amount",
                      "sports_catagory": "billing.feeSummary[&5].sportsCategories[&1].sportType"
                    }
                  },
                  "#DISCOUNTED": "billing.feeSummary[#2].feeType"
                },
                "Non Recurring fee": {
                  "@2,fee_details": {
                    "*": {
                      "total": "billing.feeSummary[&5].sportsCategories[&1].amount",
                      "sports_catagory": "billing.feeSummary[&5].sportsCategories[&1].sportType"
                    }
                  },
                  "#NON_RECURRING": "billing.feeSummary[#4].feeType"
                },
                "Recurring fee": {
                  "@2,fee_details": {
                    "*": {
                      "total": "billing.feeSummary[&5].sportsCategories[&1].amount",
                      "sports_catagory": "billing.feeSummary[&5].sportsCategories[&1].sportType"
                    }
                  },
                  "#RECURRING": "billing.feeSummary[#4].feeType"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  { // convert the values of sportType attributes to uppercase 
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "billing": {
        "feeSummary": {
          "*": {
            "sportsCategories": {
              "*": {
                "sportType": "=toUpper"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: what does [&5] and [&1] means here, how to read it?

Comment: Hi @PrasadSDeshpande  [&5] means going 5 levels up the tree and grabbing the values of the related indexes

Comment: added small correction, I am stuck to create additionalInfo array as mentioned in modified question @Barbaros Özhan

Comment: OK, I've edited as desired @PrasadSDeshpande , take care.

Comment: In Case of additionalInfo, it looks like little bit hardcoding, the given json is symbolic json, I have json much complicate, where sometimes few properties present in input JSON sometimes it does not, when property does not exist it is adding null to that particular index

Comment: Yes, it's hardcoding as it should be be. Since no way out to combine those irrelative patterns @PrasadSDeshpande

Comment: then how to maintain sequence as there are many properties I need to keep it in additionalInfo some can come with value some can not so array index might mismatch

Comment: Depends how your JSON value is built up, unfortunately hard to tell before seeing the JSON if it doesn't have a definite relation among elements @PrasadSDeshpande

Comment: I have managed it by keep all additional info properties at root level in subsequent chain of operation added shift operation to move these properties to additionalInfo array